# css - Position image at back of another image

Tags: html, image, css, position

I have a logo on my main page and i have a big image on the right side of it, what i want to do is that the image should come behind the logo.

For more clearance here is the screen shot:
[image]

The big image is the image with lots of different images inside it and the logo is the red image.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_43791/wp-content/themes/theme2033/images/logo.png" width="170" height="240" alt="LOGO" id="logo" />
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_43791/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/testi1.jpg" width="800" height="328" alt="Welcome to Our Site!" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
html, body {
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
/******HEADER******/
 #header {
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    height: 54px;
}
/******LOGO******/
 #logo {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 47px;
}
/******NAV MENU******/
 #nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/TKDQM/)

Comment: Have you tried z index

Comment: If you want elements to display on top of each other, you are going to need some help from `z-index` and a `position` that isn't `static`

Comment: Building on what Cody said. try position:relative; z-index:1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#slider{
    position: absolute;
    left:47px;
    top: 54px;
    z-index: -1;
}`
Just threw this together, not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for though. http://jsfiddle.net/TKDQM/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: absolute` to your logo image. That removes it from the flow of the page and as a result the other image gets pulled up. See it in your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/TKDQM/9/

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning on your logo and take the slider out of your header.  The header is only 54px high and not going to accommodate your slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/TKDQM/8/

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_43791/wp-content/themes/theme2033/images/logo.png" width="170" height="240" alt="LOGO" id="logo" />
</div>
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_43791/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/testi1.jpg" width="800" height="328" alt="Welcome to Our Site!" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
/******HEADER******/
 #header {
    background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    height: 54px;
    position: relative;
}
/******LOGO******/
 #logo {
   position: absolute;
    margin-left: 47px;
}
/******NAV MENU******/
 #nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
```